# Remove the [multiple-choice] tag, shall we?

Tags: discussion, tags

I happened to [review an edit suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/218364) for the [multiple-choice] tag wiki excerpt. I chose to "reject", adding custom comment "unnecessary tag". Coincidentally, another senior user had also done the same, minutes before me.

So I just went ahead and removed the tag from the [only 8 questions it had](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice). Which I hope didn't mess up the "active" feed for all.

All the 8 questions had some sort of learner vibe to it, asking to select a word from a list. But we already have a better tag [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) for it. The one remaining question is locked by community, as it's the ghost of a migrated question.

So, shall we delete the tag? If not, why should we keep it?

Comment: I think you were perfectly justified. I hope you added the appropriate tags (I can't be asked to go through all 8 questions)

Comment: Given that you removed the tag from all but one question and that it doesn’t have a tag wiki, it’s hard to tell its intention and thus to judge about its usefulness now. I admit that it doesn’t sound particularly useful though.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the one remaining question is locked by community, and it's the ghost of a migrated question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft All the 8 questions had some sort of learner vibe to it, asking to select a word from a list. But we already have a better tag "word-choice" for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone, presumably a mod, removed the tag from the migration stub. Thus, the roomba will take care of the tag. So the issue is solved. It's always better to consolidate on an existing tag than allow the creation of new tags. That's one of the reasons why the 10k tools offer a section about newly created tags.

The taxonomy got a bit better. :)